# Jquery form submit not working when using .load()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a php form that works fine when I open it directly. The submit button will add records to several tables as needed (using MySQL).

But when I load the page into a div on another page, clicking the submit button does not add the records.

Here is JS

```
$('.tab_content').hide();
$('ul.tabs li:first').addClass("active").show();
$('.tab_content:first').show();

$('ul.tabs li').click(function () {
    $('ul.tabs li').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $('.tab_content').hide();
    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    $(activeTab).fadeIn(200, function () {
        $(this).load($(this).attr("id") + ".php?" + Math.random());
    });
            return false;
});
```

So for example it is load **example.php**, and now, if, in the file will be some submit form, the button not work, like this simple with html

```
<form id="history" method="post" action="some_action.php">
<input type="text" name="test" id="test">
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Thanks for answer )

Comment: How to change this .click(function()... to .on('click','ul.tabs li',function() ... ? I thing here is the problem, thanks

Comment: Dont need help any more! Find other option to do what i need. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you get the href value correctly..then:

Use `$.ajax();` instead and try this:

```
<input type="button" id="do_submit" value="submit" name="submit">
```

then:

```
$("#do_submit").click(function(){
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: yourURLvariable,
  success: function(data){
  $("#result_target").html(data);
}
 });
});
```

Comment: this is not work. the submit button still not submit

Comment: did you triggered the click event? @Misha

Comment: Now it work for me with "$(this).on('submit', '#something', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); .... $.ajax({... });  });"